# Google App Engine free version uses more than 1 GB per day of outgoing bandwidth

Tags: google-app-engine, bandwidth, billing

I just enabled billing just because my daily bandwidth seemed to exceed 1 GB per day.

But I realized from the Billing History section, days before the day the billing is enabled, the daily bandwidth has exceeded 1 GB (even it ever reached 2.5 GB, and the last column says $0.18), and I was not charged anything.

How come the free version of app engine allows more than 1 GB of bandwidth? If it is so, then there is no purpose of enabling billing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your application to work reliably and serve all requests, you should enable billing when about to get over the limits. Sometimes (for example, if you are at 0.8GB and someone starts 500MB download) you may get a little bit over the quota, but this is usually rare and I would not try to build my business on this.